# JSDoc - What does it mean to return * from a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsdoc

Using [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), the following [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) documentation was generated:

```
/**
 * Patient retrieval success action
 * @param {Object} patient - Patient object returned from getPatient search query
 * @returns {{type, patient: *}}
 */
export const getPatientSuccess = patient => ({
  type: PATIENT_LOADED,
  patient,
});
```

In this context, `patient` is an object that may contain variable information. Here is another section with a similar JSDoc generated comment:

```
/**
 * Functional stateless component to display medication data
 * @param medications
 * @returns {*}
 * @constructor
 */
const Medications = ({ medications }) => {
  if (medications.status === 'success') {
    // Return table of medications if available
    return (/** Table of medications */);
  }

  // Return NoDataView by default if no meds are available
  return (
    <NoDataView
      heading="Data Unavailable"
      subtext="Medications data unavailable"
      isGlyphHidden={false}
    />
  );
};
```

In this context, variable component information may be returned. Is that simply what `@returns {*}` means?

Comment: I assume it means return the entire `(*)` table of medications.

Comment: @JustinJmnz no, it denotes a concrete type, not what it represents. `*` is a wild card, though, so it basically means "can be an array, string, number, boolean, WHO KNOWS!". Or more realistically it's probably something like object or array of objects. Alternatively, somebody just got lazy when typing the JSDoc, as you can just say something like `{String|Array<String>}` if you're returning a limited amount of types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSDocs, type info is generally wrapped in curly brackets for `@returns` and `@param` attributes.

`@return {*}` specifies that the function *returns the type `*`*.

`*` is a wildcard that stands for *any type*.

In other words, **the function can return any type**.

---

Check out the [JSDocs docs](http://usejsdoc.org) for more info.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this in the documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It means

> {*} Whatever you want

[In the documantation you can see](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html) and here is a doc of the returns [returns](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-returns.html)